# Explanation on the ending of "End Game"

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, end-game

I didn't understand the ending of the movie *End Game*. Could someone please explain?

- What did the reporter leaving the First Lady's house at the end have to do with anything?
- Why wasn't the identity of the president's mistress revealed?
- Did the First Lady have Stevens orchestrate it all?

Also any other added things that might help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

[The movie's Wikipedia entry explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_Game_(2006_film)):

> Alex arrives at the first lady's home to see the car that left
>   Steven's house pulling away. Alex discovers that the First Lady wanted
>   her husband killed - due to the fact that the President was being
>   unfaithful to her.
>
> A few weeks later Kate and Alex have dinner. Alex decides that
>   protecting the dead President's reputation is more important than
>   implicating his widow, and tells Kate that he still does not know who
>   wanted the President dead.